# How to insert a large record into Orient DB using pyOrient?

Tags: python, pandas, orientdb, pyorient

I have an orientDB database with a vertex type 'node'.

The node vertex has a string property called 'data'.

I am trying to insert roughly 5 to 10mb into the node's data property, however, the database seems to become non responsive when doing so.

I am using pyOrient as a driver, and the data is a pandas data frame which I have serialised to message pack format.

Is there a way to insert properties with large properties? Is the limitation at the database end, at the pyOrient end, or something else altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Binary Data](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Binary-Data.html) page in the Orient DB docs, it is possible to save the binary as a file in the file system, and then simply keep a reference to the file within the database. This has worked relatively well for me.